# Can't configure new assembly in self host application

Tags: c#, razor, nancy

I have created a new self hosted web application with NancyFX in a Windows Forms application written in C#. I added Razor support, and I managed to route to a Razor View, no problem. The problem I have is when I try to bind some data to the page, passing to the View a DataTable. Nancy complains that it cant reference the typee System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent, as there's no System assembly on the project. I read a lot of posts about adding the "razor" section in the app.config, defining the asseblies and namespaces I need. But when I try to to this, I get another error when I try to start the host:

> An unhandled exception of type
>   'Nancy.TinyIoc.TinyIoCResolutionException' occurred in Nancy.dll
>
> Additional information: Unable to resolve type:
>   Nancy.ViewEngines.ViewEngineApplicationStartup

Here is the app.config I have

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
      <section name="razor" type="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorConfigurationSection, Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webPages:Enabled" value="false" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0">
      <assemblies>
        <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      </assemblies>
    </compilation>
  </system.web>
  <system.web.webPages.razor>
    <pages pageBaseType="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase">
      <namespaces>
        <add namespace="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
        <add namespace="System" />
      </namespaces>
    </pages>
  </system.web.webPages.razor>

  <razor disableAutoIncludeModelNamespace="false">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </assemblies>
    <namespaces>
      <add namespace="System" />
    </namespaces>
  </razor>
</configuration>
```

Can you help me out with this? Even if I read all this posts, I can't find a real example about doing a self host application with Razor support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just created an repository in GitHub for you.
It's a simple solution that Mix Self hosting and Razor.

Check if it is what you searching:
[NancySelfHostRazorTest](https://github.com/RafaelDelboni/NancySelfHostRazorTest)

Good luck.

## Update

I was able to replicate your error, even with Nancy.Hosting.Aspnet. This is what I did to solve:

#### Change your config sections Add this line:

```
<section name="razor" type="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorConfigurationSection, Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
```

And bellow the section add this:

```
<razor disableAutoIncludeModelNamespace="false">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </assemblies>
  </razor>
```

In the end you will end with something like this, based on my Web.Config:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name="razor" type="Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.RazorConfigurationSection, Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor" />
    <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
      <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <razor disableAutoIncludeModelNamespace="false">
    <assemblies>
      <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
    </assemblies>
  </razor>
```

#### In the View, try something [like this](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/asp-net-mvc-simple-view-to-display-contents-of-datatable):

```
@using System.Data; 

@inherits Nancy.ViewEngines.Razor.NancyRazorViewBase<System.Data.DataTable>

<h2>Report</h2> 

<table> 
    <thead> 
    <tr> 
    @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)     
    {          
        <th>@col.ColumnName</th> 
    }     
    </tr> 
    </thead>         
    <tbody> 
    @foreach (DataRow row in Model.Rows)     
    {         
        <tr> 
        @foreach (DataColumn col in Model.Columns)         
        {              
            <td>@row[col.ColumnName]</td> 
        }         
        </tr> 
    }     
    </tbody> 
</table>
```

> Ps: I updated the [repository](https://github.com/RafaelDelboni/NancySelfHostRazorTest), with a new Module "/data" it does exactly what you want.

Comment: Thank you Rafael, your example works as expected, I copied your app.config on my application and it works. the problem here is that if I try to bind in Razor to a DataTable as Model, I get the exception about the assembly of System.ComponentModel.MarshalByValueComponent type, and I don't know how I can instruct Nancy to include the assembly/namespace I need in the cshtml page. This is my real problem, if you change your example you'll see what I mean

Comment: Hi Sebastiano, I will try to replicate the error tonight at home, but until then did you really need a datatable in your view? Why not bound an object list with your data?

Comment: Yes, of course you're right, it's just I wanted to understand better this thing about the assembly reference in the pages. I dived a little bit in the problem, I put in the page a foreach of the DataTable (foreach(DataRow dr in Model.Rows)) and I get the error. If I change the iterator definition, intead of "DataRow dr" in "var dr" I don't get the exception anymore, so I think it's about some reference that the Razor page doesn't have, but I don't get how to add it, probably the reference to System.ComponentModel. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Sebastiano i was able to replicate the problem and updated the Answer.

Comment: Thank you Rafael, it was in effect a problem about the configuration of the app.config, now it's working without complaint! Thank you again!!!